Difficulty with 5-second Cron job using Laravel-PHP
I want to schedule a job (Task1) to be run every 5 seconds. I have the following code:
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->job(new Task1)->everyFiveSeconds(); // <----- This is the line in question

        $schedule->job(new Task2)->everyMinute();

        $interval = DB::table('settings')->where('key', 'interval')?->value ?? 5;
        $schedule->job(new Task3)->cron(StringHelper::cron24($interval));
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}

I monitor the jobs on Telescope. The job runs smoothly every 5 seconds for approximately 40 seconds (8 cycles). However, it then skips about 4 cycles around the zero-second mark. For example
2024-08-28 06:47:24 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 9ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:47:29 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 7ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:47:34 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 7ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:47:39 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ....... 10ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:47:44 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ....... 10ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:47:49 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 7ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:47:54 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ....... 12ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:47:59 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 9ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:48:22 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ...... 314ms DONE <--- a jump here
2024-08-28 06:48:22 Running [App\Services\Task2]  11ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:48:22 Running [App\Services\Task3]  13ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:48:27 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 9ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:48:32 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 8ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:48:37 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 6ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:48:42 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 8ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:48:47 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 8ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:48:52 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 6ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:48:57 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 5ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:49:11 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ...... 170ms DONE <--- a jump here
2024-08-28 06:49:11 Running [App\Services\Task2]  17ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:49:16 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 7ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:49:21 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 7ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:49:26 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ....... 21ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:49:31 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ....... 12ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:49:36 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ....... 14ms DONE
2024-08-28 06:49:41 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 9ms DONE

Task1 runs in less than 1 second. We use Vapor serverless architecture and SQS on AWS.
When I change the duration to 1 minute (everyMinute), the task runs perfectly well at the exact 1 minute mark.
When I change the duration fo 15 seconds (everyFifteenSeconds), the job is run correctly every 15 seconds.
When I remove the other two tasks (Task2 and Task3), the 5-second task runs a bit better, but still jumps at the minutes.
2024-08-28 07:21:31 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 7ms DONE
2024-08-28 07:21:36 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ....... 13ms DONE
2024-08-28 07:21:41 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 8ms DONE
2024-08-28 07:21:46 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 5ms DONE
2024-08-28 07:21:51 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 8ms DONE
2024-08-28 07:21:56 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 6ms DONE
2024-08-28 07:22:11 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ....... 91ms DONE <--- a jump here
2024-08-28 07:22:16 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 7ms DONE
2024-08-28 07:22:21 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 7ms DONE
2024-08-28 07:22:26 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 7ms DONE
2024-08-28 07:22:31 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 9ms DONE
2024-08-28 07:22:36 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 8ms DONE
2024-08-28 07:22:41 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 8ms DONE
2024-08-28 07:22:46 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 8ms DONE
2024-08-28 07:22:51 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 6ms DONE
2024-08-28 07:22:56 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 7ms DONE
2024-08-28 07:23:08 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ....... 88ms DONE <--- a jump here
2024-08-28 07:23:13 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 9ms DONE
2024-08-28 07:23:18 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 5ms DONE
2024-08-28 07:23:23 Running [App\Jobs\Task1] ........ 5ms DONE

Any ideas what could be the reason(s)? Or how can I solve the issue? Thanks.

Have you tested if running the task in its own dedicated queue still makes the issue persist? (relevent docs: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/scheduling#scheduling-queued-jobs)

This all based on conjecture, but from what I can see your code simply takes 5 seconds to run 1 task. So, as long as you perform 1 task it will do it every 5 seconds. Do 2 tasks and it takes 10 seconds, 3 tasks in 15 seconds and 4 in 20. That perfectly matched your Telescope results.

Thanks @MatthewBradley Thanks for your comment. We'll try it and let you know.

Thanks @KIKOSoftware. I am not sure if I understand your comment. The tasks are scheduled to be run every 5 seconds. Each task takes only a few milliseconds to execute. Or, am I missing something here?

I might not have worded it correctly, I shouldn't have said that it takes 5 seconds to run 1 task. I meant: "each 5 second 1 task is ran". Check the times reported by Telescope, the intervals are always plurals of 5 seconds, and correspond with the amount of tasks you perform. The assumption is there's another task running every minute which you haven't told us about.

Thanks again @MatthewBradley; we separated the queues and it didn't help. I find the solution and I have posted here.

After a lot of searching, apparently it is due to the way that Vapor handles sub-minute jobs. It uses AWS EventBridge. EventBridge is launched at every minute. This takes time to become fully functional. Hence, missing some seconds at the beginning of each minute. Please see this blog for details https://blog.laravel.com/vapor-sub-minute-scheduled-tasks
Basically you need to have this in your vapor.yml:
environments:
    production:
        scheduler: sub-minute
        queue-concurrency: 2
        cli-timeout: 120

Additionally you need to make sure:

cli-timeout is a value >= 120
cli-concurrency is >= 2
Vapor Core >= v2.34.0


Howdy, it's noteworthy that even cron jobs do not schedule correctly in under-sub-minute intervals. And if you receive a load where your first job isn't finished by the time your second kicks off, you can run into a bad situation. For jobs like this, I prefer an always-running process in the background that is managed using systemd.

Maybe garbage collection is getting into action - https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.performance-considerations.php#features.gc.performance-considerations.slowdowns
Try to disable it and experiment more.

Thanks Uladzimir. But I don't think this is the cause of it:

the whole system is on serverless architecture, running on Lambda functions on AWS. Therefore, I believe the memory management is done efficiently by AWS (both expansion and garbage collection, if any).
the procedure does not happen that many times, or does not require much memory. Each task is as small as 2-4 database query.

But thanks again.
